# the detail in react list render

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs

for the first way in render():

```js
const arr = [<li>{numbers[0]}</li>,<li>{numbers[0]}</li>,<li>{numbers[1]}</li>]
return (
<ul>{arr}</ul>
);
```

it runs occur a warning which i can understand:
**Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique 'key' prop.**

but for other way:

```js
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{numbers[0]}</li>
      <li>{numbers[0]}</li>
      <li>{numbers[1]}</li> 
    </ul>
  );
```

It runs ok,no warning..


the two ways to render a list above should generate the same virtual dom。but i dont understand why the second way runs with no warning like the first way happen. 
can somebody tells why? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is React requirement for loops. You can find more info on https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: thanks, but why this requirement is not needed when we do not use loops , like the second way above ?

Comment: Because there is no loop. Unique keys are required for tags in loops.

Comment: It's really a requirement for array-based lists components. There's no loops in the code above.

Comment: ok , i just a little confused in list-render and dom diff , i can fix it . thanks